# Why should an action in SR be a lorentz scalar?

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action, invariants

I have taken it granted that an action in the special relativity must be a lorentz scalar. However is there a fundamental reason for this requirement? I cannot think of a plausible reason for this question.

Comment: See these previous questions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96009/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does action really have to be Lorentz-invariant in SR?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96009/) and/or [Must the action be a Lorentz scalar?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13522/84967).

Answer (score -1):

Because in QFT you impose a Poincaré invariance and Poincaré includes Lorentz, this comes from the fact that physics must not depend from the frame you choose and so has to be rotation/translation(and boost for a Minkowskian metric) invariant, so your Lagrangian has to be what we call "Lorentz scalar" ie invariant under any Lorentz transfo.

Comment: OP didn't say anything about QFT though...